# How to distinguish between a letter/number and an arrow/ f1/ f2.?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I am using pyqt5 for writing a text editor.

While overriding the eventFilter method, I want to know when a regular key is pressed (such as a letter or a number) and when an arrow is pressed (or shift, capsLK, f1, f2.- everything which is not really wrriten on the document).

I know I can check every single case like- if key == QtCore.Qt.Key_Left, elif key == QtCore.Qt.Key_Right... and so on.
But there is a more efficient and simple way to do that without checking every single case?

Comment: use `event.text()`

Comment: It might be worth noting that `event.text()` will return a non-empty string for some keys (e.g. ESC, DEL and BACKSPACE) that normally either don't modify the document at all, or may remove rather than add characters. Also, the [docs say](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeyevent.html#text) that the return value when keyboard modifiers are present may be platform-dependent to some extent. This might be relevant if your editor is based on a qt-widget that uses some of built-in [standard shortcuts](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeysequence.html#standard-shortcuts).

Comment: @ekhumoro I always had problems reimplementing text controls in a simple way in order to differentiate whenever a key event actually results in a (*possible*) "typed" text or not. Depending on the situation I handled that differently, but the result is almost always doing various checks against groups of standard shortcuts, I wonder if there's a more straightforward way to do so, maybe by trying to implement what `QInputControl.isAcceptableInput()` does?

Comment: @musicamante Yes, filtering on the value of `text()` is the right way to go, but the exact handling will probably be application specific. The approach taken by `isAcceptableInput` seems a reasonable place to start (the source code for which can be viewed [here](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/gui/text/qinputcontrol.cpp.html#_ZNK13QInputControl17isAcceptableInputEPK9QKeyEvent)).